# Unit Testing Directives in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Im new to angular js testing. We are using Karma/Jasmine to test. I am trying to unit test a directive. Essentially I want to make sure that once it is all compiled that element now contains 'id="tf-' ......  I have verified using dump(element); that in fact i am getting the result im after but my test is not testing it how it should.

in my test file i do this:

```
var $scope,element;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = engular.element('<div tf-swf></div');
    $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    dump(element);
})); 

describe('tfSwf directive' , function() {
    it('should place element into DOM' , function() {
        expect(element).toContain('<div id="tf');
    });
});
```

so here is the issue ... when i run this it fails and i get an error along the lines of:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'indexOf' at null.<anonymous>
```

I know it looks wierd that im dumping that elemnt but this is the output:

```
Object{0: <div tf-swf=""><div id="tf-2403-place"></div></div>, length: 1}
```

the fact that the inner div exists and has an id that includes a random number is exactly what im after ... i just cant figure out how to find that inner div in my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to test if the element object contains a substring. You should first convert the element object to a string:

```
expect('' + element).toContain('<div id="tf');
```

Comment: this works . thank you . For reference if anyone else sumbles on this question i found that angular.element returns a jquery object so i was able to do this:  expect(element.html()).toContain('<div id="tf');

Comment: To be exact, it returns a jqLite object, unless jQuery is available, in which case it returns a jQuery object. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element